# Join two keys and corresponding values in a list with a character

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have two lists, say

```
x = [{'name':'sri'}], y= [{'job':'nothing'}]
```

I want to join the two keys into one key and the values into one value, say

```
z = [{'name/job':'sri/nothing'}]
```

I have tried the following

```
z = x.update(y[0])
z[0:1] = ["/".join(z[0:1])]
```

but it shows list doesnot have update attribute error.

I have tried to combine two lists like

```
z = x+y 
# z=[{'name':'sri'},{'job':'nothing'}]
```

and tried to combine keys, but couldn't find a solution

Note: x and y always have only key-value pair respectively.

Comment: This does not seem like a good idea as you are losing information. Why do you need that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `zip()` to pair up your dictionaries, then pair up the key-value pairs in each to generate output dictionaries:

```
result = [
    {'{}/{}'.format(k1, k2): '{}/{}'.format(v1, v2) for (k1, v1), (k2, v2) in zip(d1.items(), d2.items())}
    for d1, d2 in zip(x, y)
]
```

Demo:

```
>>> x = [{'name': 'sri'}]
>>> y = [{'job': 'nothing'}]
>>> [
...     {'{}/{}'.format(k1, k2): '{}/{}'.format(v1, v2) for (k1, v1), (k2, v2) in zip(d1.items(), d2.items())}
...     for d1, d2 in zip(x, y)
... ]
[{'name/job': 'sri/nothing'}]
```

The above list and dict comprehension combination essentially does this:

```
result = []
for d1, d2 in zip(x, y):
    # d1 and d2 are a pair of dictionaries from lists x and y, respectively.
    newdict = {}
    for (k1, v1), (k2, v2) in zip(d1.items(), d2.items()):
        # k1 and v1 are a key-value pair from d1, and
        # k2 and v2 are a key-value pair from d2. This loop runs just once
        # when your input dictionaries have only one key-value each.
        key = '{}/{}'.format(k1, k2)    # new key with k1/k2 combined
        value = '{}/{}'.format(v1, v2)  # new value with v1/v2 combined
        newdict[key] = value
    result.append(newdict)
```

but without the intermediate variables.

The solution assumes that `x` and `y` consist of an equal number of dictionaries (any extra elements in one of the lists will be ignored). Each dictionary pair is assumed to have the same number of key-value pairs (again, extra key-value pairs in one dictionary will be ignored), and the key-value pairs of any dictionary pair are combined in *current dictionary order*. For dictionaries with only a single key each that order doesn’t matter.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution.  I have understood it and copied the same, but the problem is it is showing syntax error. `key = f'{k1}/{k2}'` in this line.

Comment: @SriHarsha that means you are using a Python version < 3.6. I’ll update.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a small loop and then formatted strings for your `keys` and `values`

```
z = {}
for k, v in x.items():
    for a, b in y.items():
        z['{}/{}'.format(k, a)] = '{}/{}'.format(v, b)
```

> ```
> {'name/job': 'sri/nothing'}
> ```